# How to turn off cascading delete for more than one 1 to 1 table relationships to the same table in Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have the following table structure simplified

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}

public class Buyer
{
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

public class Seller
{
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int BuyerId { get; set; }
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public <OrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int OrderLineNo { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

When I run Update_Database command I get the following error

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Buyers_dbo.UserProfile_UserId' on table 'Buyers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

My Buyer and Seller tables have a 1 to 1 relationship with to the UserProfile on UserId so I understand that when you delete a Buyer it can't delete the UserProfile since there might be a Seller and vice versa.

So I want to turn off cascading deletes for just the Buyer to the User and the Seller to the User  using the fluid syntax but I can't get something to work so would appreciate if someone could help.

I have looked through the other StackOVerflow questions for the same error but couldn't find one that matches my scenario.

Extra: If I rename the UserId in my Buyer table  to DummyUserId then the Uppdate-Database command works but this is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can disable cascade deletes using `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);`

So for your mapping, you **may** have something similar to the following:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Buyer>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: The Map method renamed the foreign key from UserId to UserID in the database so I can still refer to it as UserId in the code. Is there a way to not have the UserId database column in the Buyer table renamed to UserID but keep it UserId so my db column naming convention stays consistent?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on my part, you should be able to use `Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"))`. Updated. The important bit is the `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false);` (which you can add to your existing mapping setup).

Comment: If it is UserId the Update-Database command gives error Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
(54,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'UserId' was already defined.